# Unable to open ports on the virgin media super hub VMDG480, anybody have/had this issue and has a fix?

Tags: router, port-forwarding

Recently got 30Mbps broadband from Virgin Media and the gave us a modem/router super hub (VMDG480), I have tried opening ports for a couple of game servers but when I check these, they are still closed, the only port I can get open is 80. I have looked on Google for a fix, but come across none, any ideas?